# Cannot install grails plugin Jaces-cannot resolve

Tags: grails

Tried putting this line in the plugin section fo BuildConfig.groovy:

```
build ":jaces:1.7.2.2"
```

and also added the repo

```
mavenRepo "http://jaces.googlecode.com/svn/"
```

Getting this error:

```
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:jaces:1.7.2.2
```

Also getting the error if I take out the build directive and just try the install-plugin command.

using grails 2.2

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The information on the grails portal is outdated. I am trying to update it. Please refer to http://jaces.org instead.

There you will find instructions for downloading the plugin binary from google code and installing to a Grails application.

I will post another message when the Grails portal page is updated.

Thanks